# GAE/Python - What is the best way to pass the request from the controller to the model?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, request

In the following example code I illustrate how I solved passing the request from the controller to the model.  Is there a better way to do this?

models/MyModel.py

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class MyModel(db.model):
    a = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    b = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    c = db.StringProperty(required=True)

class Update:
    def __init__(self, x)
        self.x = x

    def do_something(self)
        myquery = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM MyModel WHERE a = :1' self.x)
        v = myquery.get()

        if not v:
            somevalue = MyModel(a = self.request.get('a'), # Doesn't work unless
                                b = self.request.get('b'), # the request has been
                                c = self.request.get('c')) # passed
            somevalue.put()
```

controllers/MyController.py

```
import webapp2
from models.MyModel import Update

class WebHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        var_x = "string"
        var_y = "string"
        z = Update(var_x)
        z.request = self.request  # <--- Is there a better way?
        z.do_something()
```

Edit: (5/30/2012)
I ended up creating a function to pass the request variables to the Model as arguments.  I was hoping there was some python magic that would avoid all the repetition but I didn't find one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

handing over the request to the model means you're mixing model and controller.

normaly the model shouldn't even be aware that ther even is a request. geting the parameters from the request is the controller's job, not the models. if your `do_something` method has to work with parameters, then it should get them as arguments and return a result (usually an entity).

Answer (score 2):

You need a little more encapsulation.  Another level of abstraction is useful.

Create a class representing the actual thing that you're using `MyModel` to persist, with `a`, `b`, and `c` attributes or properties:

```
class Thing(object):

   def __init__(a, b, c):
      self.a = a
      self.b = b
      self.c = c
```

This class doesn't know anything about requests, or the datastore, or persistence.  It's where all the actual business logic surrounding the thing itself lives.

You can instantiate this class without needing a request or a database, and you can unit test all of the business logic without having to mock out any of GAE's plumbing.

You can then write code in your request handler that instantiates this thing, e.g.:

```
def get(request):
  thing = Thing(a=request.get('a'), b=request.get('b'), c=request.get('c'))
  u = Update(some_params)
  u.do_something(thing)
```

You can add a class method to `MyModel` that puts a thing, e.g.:

```
@classmethod
def put_thing(thing):
  model = MyModel(a=thing.a, b=thing.b, c=thing.c)
  model.put()
```

and then your `do_something` logic can just call `MyModel.put_thing(thing)` if it needs to add it to the database.

Comment: Or you could just pass the arguments for `thing` direct to `do_something`.

Comment: If `Thing` is nontrivial enough that you need a database to persist it, it's probably nontrivial enough that you don't want to pass all its attributes individually to every method that works on it.

Comment: But you don't need a database to persist it - you just invented it in your answer, as a container for items to pass to a method on MyModel.

Comment: The database is present in the original question.

Comment: Yes, but the `Thing` kind isn't - and there's no need for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add update as a class method to the MyModel class with a @classmethod decorator and call MyModel.update(a=x)